# How to display an excel loading screen while computing data in office addin?

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm writing an Office Excel addin-in.
When the user enters a new value in a cell, some computation is done in the addin.
Sometimes, it's slow and I would like to display a loading screen during this time.

My first thought was to display a modal containing a spinner, but the user can still interact with the excel document, and eventually change the "soon-to-be-outdated" data.

Is there another way to display a loading screen (or at least, to freeze the excel document) while computing data?

Edit: My addin is developed in Javascript with OfficeJS and Office react fabric UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use [WorksheetProtection](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheetprotection?product=excel) for this.

```
Excel.run(function(ctx) {
  // get a reference to Sheet1
  var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");

  // Protect Sheet1
  sheet.protection.protect({
    allowEditObjects: false,
    allowEditScenarios: false
  });

  return ctx.sync();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel loading screen is pretty "vague". Still, with office-js something like this is possible:

1. Create a new worksheet
2. Write "Thank you for waiting"
3. Set the worksheet Visible property to hidden - https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheet?product=excel
4. Whenever there is a calculation - change the visibility to Visbile and select it.
5. At the end delete the worksheet.

Comment: I'm using [office-js](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office), the javascript api for office so I don't think I can use a UserForm.

Comment: @blandine - honestly, I also do not know about the `UserForm` with office-js. However, you can try putting a shape and displaying it! :) Or creating a very hidden worksheet, writing on it only "Thank you for waiting", making it visible whenever you run the program. At the end you may delete the worksheet. https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheet?product=excel